# Adding PouchDB to Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, pouchdb

What is the best way to include `pouchdb-browser` to a project's Webpack config?

The PouchDB documentation mentions customs builds should use Webpack:

https://pouchdb.com/custom.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation refers to building a customized PouchDB build, which you will not need probably.

For using PouchDb, just `require()` it in your normal JavaScript code and use it:

```
// ES5
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb-browser');
var db = new PouchDB('dbname');

db.put({
  _id: 'dave@gmail.com',
  name: 'David',
  age: 69
});
```

That's it! Webpack will resolve and bundle PouchDB automatically!

Comment: I created a module(file) and named it database.js. Included pouchdb in this file as above then included database.js were needed and webpack dealt with the rest.